# G-Code for resetting to 100% speed

Tags: g-code, slic3r

I had problems printing parts and I figured out that my children have turned the knob of my Prusa i3 MK3 and set the printing speed to 112%.

Since I'm not experimenting much yet, I'm not printing at different speeds than the original speed. I wonder whether there's a G-Code command that I could let Slic3r insert at the beginning of each print to ensure the print starts with 100% speed.

Comment: you know that the print speed is swapped to 100% whenever you start the printer, right?

Comment: @Trish I thought so also, unless you save it with M500 perhaps? Anyways `M220 S100` will put it back to 100 %.

Comment: @Trish: yes, if I power the printer off and on. However, I sometimes print several parts in a row.

Comment: The RealAnswer(TM) is to lock those kids up and keep them away :-)  -- or Epoxy the knob so it can't be moved...

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: sure, I'll explain to them and try to apply some countermeasures. However, this could also have happened to me. On the other hand side I'm happy to see them interested in 3D technology

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put the speed to 100 % by G-code command: `M220 S100`.

The `M220`command is described [here](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M220:_Set_speed_factor_override_percentage).

Know that speed changes sent to the printer have an effect on the next printed layer, it first finishes the current layer at the speed commanded before starting printing the layer.

Comment: Works on my Kobra Max, during a 6 day print where my ink swap was missed - THANK YOU